# What does activemq broker mean?

Tags: java, jms

I'm new to `ActiveMQ` and `JMS` and started with exploring how the hello world program works.

I've installed `ActiveMQ` server and run it. Now, I created a desctop application and copy-and-paste [apache_activemq_official_hello_world](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html) into it. When I tried to run it, I got the following exception:

```
Caught: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:252)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:265)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:184)
    at com.badmitrii.App$HelloWorldProducer.run(App.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext.registerMBean(ManagementContext.java:366)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.AnnotatedMBean.registerMBean(AnnotatedMBean.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startManagementContext(BrokerService.java:2370)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:567)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.doCompositeConnect(VMTransportFactory.java:124)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.doConnect(VMTransportFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:250)
    ... 5 more
```

And after that

```
Sent message: 386233378 : Thread-13
Sent message: 535117374 : Thread-16
Sent message: 1659874841 : Thread-17
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-17 : 56191182
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-16 : 1728802812
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-13 : 1191507779
Sent message: 1424811745 : Thread-22
Sent message: 1340394669 : Thread-25
Sent message: 1585379622 : Thread-29
Sent message: 607795742 : Thread-27
Sent message: 807925334 : Thread-32
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-22 : 1629703769
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-29 : 2145661378
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-25 : 1459121566
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-27 : 1628632972
Received: Hello world! From: Thread-32 : 538611977
Received: null
```

My question is do I really need in ActiveMQ server in that example and what is `ActiveMQ Broker` mentioned in the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I think, all you need is only activemq-all-?.??.?.jar. The example does all by itself. If your ActiveMQ server is started, you can stop it. After launching your "Hello ActiveMQ" app you maybe will not see the exception. But it is better to insert

> Thread.sleep(3000); //my fighting against exceptions (could not create transport)

before creation of the first consumer.